# Transform non-linear to linear function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, linear-transformations

Can someone explain me why the following function is non-linear?

$y = 2x_1^2 + 8x_2^2 + 4x_1x_2 + 8x_2 + 9x_1$

due to the two terms $2x_1^2, 8x_2^2$ or due to the $4x_1x_2$ term?

and if I want to transform to linear with transformation I can?

Comment: All three terms a non-linear and you can't linearize them.

Comment: You can linearize it by adding new variable, it depends what is you goal, in regression theory the basic idea is to define : $x_3 = x_1^2$, $x_4= x_2^2$ and $x_5 = x_1x_2$

Comment: @ALG Thanks for your replay. Can you give me an example of a $\varphi(x) $ which makes the above transformation. Also any link?

Comment: I mean, you need to add some variable so probably is not what you looking for, since you will land in a spece with 5 independent variable, btw the transformation is eactly what i wrote i.d. add variables $x_3, x_4,x_5$ definined as before. What is you pourpose?